# Angular - How to trigger a GET request in one component and inject the result into another

Tags: angular

Consider two separate Angular components:

1. A table
2. A card, which contains a form

When clicking a row of the table, I want to send a GET request to a REST API requesting data, which I want to show inside my form.

For this purpose, I have implemented a FormCrudService with the following important method:

```
  getFormDetails(id: number): Observable<FormDetails>{
    return this.httpClient.get<FormDetails>(this.URL + '/' + id);
  }
```

This method is sending the GET request to retrieve the data I want to show in my form. The method, however, requires an id as parameter. This id equals the row index of the table row I click to trigger the GET request. My idea was to inject the FormCrudService into my card-component, so that I can send the GET request from within the card-component. I still need to find a way, however, to inform the card-component about which row I have clicked. And since I don't know any better way, I have created another service, a SelectRowService:

```
  private selectedRow = new Subject<number>();
  selectedRow$ = this.selectedRow.asObservable();

  updateSelectedRow(id: number) {
    this.selectedRow.next(id);
  }
```

I have injected this service into my table-component and added a click-listener to my table-rows, so that when clicking a row, the `updateSelectedRow(id)` method is called. Inside my card-component, I have injected the same service and subscribed to `selectedRow$`:

```
  constructor(private formCrudService: FormCrudService, private selectRowService: SelectRowService) {
    this.selectRowService.selectedRow$.subscribe(id=> this.formCrudService.getFormDetails(id).subscribe(details => this.details= details));
  }
```

Now, in theory this doesn't work too bad. I have two issues with this solution, however:

1. I have to click twice on the table row in order to show the
   requested data inside my form.
2. I don't really like the idea of having two services for this task. Is there a way to reduce it to just a single service?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you reassign your Observable. Probably when you Inject the service into your CardComponent, the observable is still undefined, cause the method has not been called yet. But when it is called, the observable will be reassigned. The CardComponent does not know this. It subscribed to the original Observable, which is reassigned and does not emit any new value.
To fix this, you could use a Subject instead of an Observable and call `.next()` with the value as a parameter on it. Do not reassign the Subject. You can observe the Subject in your CardComponent and it should notice once the Subject emits a new value.

Here is the related docs link:
https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject

Comment: hey, thx so much for your help! I have updated my question after having tried out using Subject. I did not really know how to use a Subject since the http request returns an Observable, right? I have to deal with it, I cannot just transform it into a Subject now, can I?